# Problem with .env file and create-react-app - returns undifined

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, undefined, create-react-app

I know this question has been asked countless times, and trust me when I say I've read through pages here on Stack Overflow, as well as other websites, and have obviously gone through the documentation. There is either something I am not understanding at all, or something silly that I'm missing.

I have created a React App (using npx create-react-app) to create a little weather information service using an API and the fetch API (think it's called that?). It is all front-end (I have not started learning any back-end stuff yet).

My problem is my .env file. As stated, I've done a lot of research, and can therefore (hopefully) rule out the following:

1. My enviroment variable text file is called '.env', and is located in my root folder (i.e. in the same location as package.json file and src & public folders).
2. In the .env text file, the variable is prefixed with 'REACT_APP_'.
3. I am almost certain that all syntax and variable names are correct, but that could still be a possibility?

When I put my API key directly into my fetch, all works perfectly, but is always undefined when trying to get the API key from the .env file. I know since I'm only doing front-end, and the API is still technically visible if I push/upload to GitHub (or whatever), it doesn't really make a difference, even using .gitignore, but I still want to either fix it, or find out why it doesn't work for my own peace of mind.

As I understand, with create-react-app, no other modules/dependencies (not sure the correct term) need to be installed via the terminal, as proccess.env is all included these days. As far as I'm aware, proccess.env should work out the box with create-react-app?

Here is my code:

App.js

```
//Created by: Byron Georgopoulos
//Created on: 31/07/2020
//Last Updated on: 03/08/2020
//Description: Using Geolocation API, OpenWeatherMap API, and Fetch API, this React App displays the weather at the user current location,
//and a user can search the OpenWeatherMap database for the weather in (most) cities across the globe. 

//Import React
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//Import Fetch API
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

//Styling and React-Bootstrap
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

//Get API key from .env file
const key = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY;
console.log('API Key: ', key);

class App extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      userCity: '',
      cityInfo: [],
      showModal: false,
    };

  }

  //Use Geolocation API to find users co-ordinants
  getPos = () => {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
    });
  }

  //Get Latitude & Longitude, and search OpenWeatherMap API based on location (coords)
  getLocalWeather = async (latitude, longitude) => {
    const apiCall = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=${key}&units=metric`);
    const result = await apiCall.json();

    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
    this.setState({ cityInfo: [result] });
  }

  //When Component Mounts
  componentDidMount() {

    this.getPos()
    .then((position) => {
      this.getLocalWeather(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    })

  }

  //Handle user search
  handleCity = (event) => {
    let userCity = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ userCity: userCity });
  }

  //Search OpenWeatherMap API for user's city
  handleSubmit = () => {

    let userCity = this.state.userCity;
    this.refs.cityInput.value = '';

    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${userCity}&appid=${key}&units=metric`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          (result) => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              cityInfo: [result],
            });
          },
          (error) => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              error
            });
          }
        )
    
  }

  //Opens Help Modal
  openModal = () => 
  {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  //Closes Help Modal
  closeModal = () => 
  {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  render() {

    const error = this.state.error;
    const isLoaded = this.state.isLoaded;
    const cityInfo = this.state.cityInfo;

    if (error)
    {
      return <div>
                Error: {error.message}
              </div>;
    }
    else
    if (!isLoaded)
    {
      return <div className='LoadingMsg'>
                
                <br></br>
                <h2>Welcome to Open Weather Map API</h2>
                <hr></hr>
                <h5>Finding your location...</h5>
                <h6>Please 'Allow Location Access' in your browser to continue...</h6>
                <hr></hr>
                <br></br>

            </div>;
    }
    else
    {
      return (
        <div className='App'>
  
          <br></br>
          <h2>Open Weather Map API : Find the weather in your city.</h2>
          <hr></hr>
          <h6>This was created by Byron Georgopoulos for <a href='https://www.hyperiondev.com/' target='_blank'>HyperionDev</a> (L02T14) using
               React Components. It uses the <a href='https://openweathermap.org/api' target='_blank'>Open Weather Map API</a> and 
               the <a href='https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API' target='_blank'>Geolocation API</a> to first find 
               your current location and display the weather in your city (if access is allowed by the user), and a search bar to find the weather
              for over 200.000 cities worldwide thereafter.</h6>
          <hr></hr>
          <br></br>

          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col sm={5}>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Form id='cityForm'>
                  <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label>Please Enter A City:</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control onChange={this.handleCity} type='text' placeholder='e.g. Johannesburg' ref='cityInput' />
                    <br></br>
                    <Container>
                      <Row>
                        <Col>
                          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} variant='primary'>Search City</Button>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                          <Button onClick={this.openModal} id='helpBtn' variant='info'>Help / FAQ</Button>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Container>
                  </Form.Group>
                </Form>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={7}>
                    {cityInfo.map(item => (
                      <Card id='weatherCard'>
                        <Card.Body>
                          <Card.Title><h3>Weather for <b>{item.name}</b>, {item.sys.country}.</h3></Card.Title>
                          <hr></hr>
                          <Card.Text><h5>It is currently: ±{Math.round(item.main.temp)}° C.</h5></Card.Text>
                          <Card.Text><h5>It feels like: ±{Math.round(item.main.feels_like)}° C.</h5></Card.Text>
                          <Card.Text><h5>The weather is: {item.weather[0].main}.</h5></Card.Text>
                          <Card.Text><h5>Sky Description: {item.weather[0].description}.</h5></Card.Text>
                          <Card.Text><h5>Humidity is at: {item.main.humidity}%.</h5></Card.Text>
                          <Card.Text><h5>Wind Speed is at: {item.wind.speed}m/s.</h5></Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                      </Card>
                    ))}
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
          <br></br>
          <hr></hr>
          <br></br>
          
          <Modal id='helpModal' show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.closeModal} animation={true} centered>
            <Modal.Body>
              <h4 id='modalHeading'>Help : Searching For A City</h4>
              <hr></hr>
              <Container>
                <Row>
                  <Col sm={1}>
                    <h6>1. </h6>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={11}>
                    <h6>You can only search cities in the input field. No countries, co-ordinates, provinces, states, etc.</h6>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col sm={1}>
                    <h6>2. </h6>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={11}>
                    <h6>You can only search a cities FULL NAME. For example, LA ≠ Los Angeles, or JHB ≠ Johannesburg.</h6>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col sm={1}>
                    <h6>3. </h6>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={11}>
                    <h6>That being said, searching for a city is NOT case sensitive. For example, los angeles = Los Angeles, or johannesburg = Johannesburg.</h6>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col sm={1}>
                    <h6>4. </h6>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={11}>
                    <h6>± : Temperatures are rounded to the nearest whole number.</h6>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col sm={1}>
                    <h6>5. </h6>
                  </Col>
                  <Col sm={11}>
                    <h6>Temperatures are in Degrees Celcius.</h6>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Container>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant='danger' onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal> 

        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "weather-api",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.1",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }

}
```

.env
(no white space before or after =, no quotations, and the X's are my API key)

```
REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Other things to note:

1. macOS Catalina 10.15.6 : Macbook Pro 2017
2. Using VS Code
3. React-Bootstrap is installed
4. Using Firefox to try and run the app (via 'npm start' in my terminal)

Sorry for the long post, and if I've left anything out. Still very new to all of this, especially Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the package also:

```
npm i dotenv
```

Answer (score 0):

React read/creates `env` when is built so you need to `npm run start` every time you modify the .env file so the variables get updated.

And you don't need to install any other packages as CRA (create-react-app) already comes with `dotenv`

You should use this
`{process.env. REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY}` wherever your Key exists.

Comment: When you say restart, do you mean close my terminal, and type npm start again? And for the second part: does this mean I can't assign it as a global variable in App.js as I have?

Comment: @ByronGeorgopoulos Correct sir. Windows is `ctrl + c`. Mac is `control + c`. You can assign it to a global variable if you want, like you did. And then use it from there. But to have a better structure, I would move all your API calls into a `service.js` file and then your API key can be declared there are the top so it just exists once. If you keep the structure you have now, you will/may have multiple API calls and you'll be repeating yourself. Let me know if this make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Whenever I make big changes to my app, I completely quit my terminal (cmd+q on Mac) and re-open it, get the directory, and npm start it again, just to make sure everything is fresh. So it's definitely not that. Moving my API calls elsewhere will come, just trying to get the basics down for now. When you say  'You should use this {process.env. REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY} wherever your Key exists.', could you please elaborate? Have I done it correctly in the code I posted? Thanks again.

Comment: @ByronGeorgopoulos replace `fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${userCity}&appid=${key}&units=metric')
        .then(res => res.json())` with `fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${userCity}&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY}&units=metric')
        .then(res => res.json())` and see if that works

Comment: Still nothing. Thank you though.

Comment: @ByronGeorgopoulos Strange, I just quickly added a new `env` variable now, restarted and works. If this is in a public repo or something I can help you take a look. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Environment variables in Create React App
   We can add environment specific variables to our project by declaring them in a local JS file. By default we have NODE_ENV defined for us by CRA, and we can add any other environment variables starting with REACT_APP_.

WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app! Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app’s files.

The environment variables are embedded during the build time. Since Create React App produces a static HTML/CSS/JS bundle, it can’t possibly read them at runtime.

Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

2. Managing environment variables in .env files
   We can create a file named .env in which we can store our environment variables. This .env file will be treated as a default file to define permanent environment variables.

Now we need to create other .env files to support staging and production environments. So lets create .env.staging and .env.production files.

So the files would look like,

```
// **.env**

REACT\_APP\_TITLE = "My Awesome App"
REACT\_APP\_SESSION\_TIME = "60"

// **.env.staging**

REACT\_APP\_API\_BASE\_URL = "https://app.staging.com/api/"

// **.env.production**

REACT\_APP\_API\_BASE\_URL = "https://app.prod.com/api/"
```

3. Install env-cmd package
   Now that we have our separate env files ready we can use them make environment specific builds. For than we will use an npm package *env-cmd *.

env-cmd

This is a simple node program for executing commands using an environment from an env file. Install this package with below command,

```
**npm install env-cmd**
```

4. Create commands to create environment specific builds
   Now open your package.json file and add below scripts,

   "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   **"start:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts start",**
   **"start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts start",**
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   **"build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",**
   **"build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",**
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   }

source https://dev.to/rishikeshvedpathak/react-environment-specific-builds-using-env-with-cra-and-env-cmd-296b

Comment: So no way to get the API key from my .env without installing env-cmd when using npm start?

Comment: Yes you have to use npm packages

Answer (score 0):

For me, the .env file was located in the /src directory instead of the root directory.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, i tried all things by docs and stackoverflow. no luck